# Dealing with Type errors, size of list being dimension 1 || Monsoon Problem

Tags: python, list, types

```py
def getUmbrellas(sizes,req):
    
    try:
        if list[0]==int():
         
    else:
        print("List must be 1D")
    for i in sizes[::-1]:
        if req % int(i)==0:
          return int(req/int(i))
    return -1
```

This is my solution to the Umbrella problem in python. It takes in an input of a list of umbrella sizes and a number of people needed to cover as an int.

for example ([2, 2, 2, 4], 4) will return 1, because one size 4 umbrella will cover all 4 people.

I'm trying to deal with errors that come from the list being more than 1D and general error exceptions in python.

Can anyone help to suggest a way I could implement a check if the list is more than 1D and then exit the code with a message saying "List must be 1D"

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by checking the elements of the list or tuple passed to the function via assert:

```
assert isinstance(sizes, (list, tuple)), "sizes should be of type list or tuple."
assert all(isinstance(elem, (int, float)) for elem in sizes), "sizes should be 1D."
```

or via raise:

```
if not isinstance(sizes, (list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError("sizes should be of type list or tuple.")
if not all(isinstance(elem, (int, float)) for elem in sizes):
    raise TypeError("sizes should be 1D.)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've now realised my solution is wrong. It fails the following test case:

```
getUmbrellas([2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],4)
```

So I need to start again! I think this is a variation of the coin problem.